# Edit JSON file using JS and PHP from Text Input HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, admin

I'm creating a admin panel for a restaurant owner that want to be able to edit menu section. So I'm creating a dynamic table taking values from JSON file but I want to be able to edit JSON values typing in a input text (inside of the table), click "Confirm" and update JSON values (without refresh the page) but I'm not able.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu-container">
        <h1>Menu del Ristorante</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tipologia</th>
                    <th class="nome">Nome</th>
                    <th>Modifica</th>
                    <th>Nuovo testo</th>
                    <th>Conferma</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="menu-table">
                <!-- I dati verranno caricati qui dinamicamente -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "tipologia": "Antipasto",
        "nome": "Misto di Mare caldo e freddo (min. per 2 persone)"
    },
    {
        "tipologia": "Antipasto",
        "nome": "Carpaccio di Gambero rosso, Cetriolo, Panna acida"
    },
    {
        "tipologia": "Antipasto",
        "nome": "Tartare di Pescato, Guacamole e Pane Carasau"
    },
    {
        "tipologia": "Antipasto",
        "nome": "Bresaola di Tonno e insalata di Pesche Noci"
    },
    {
        "tipologia": "Antipasto",
        "nome": "Altra voce del menu senza descrizione"
    },
    {
        "tipologia": "Antipasto",
        "nome": "Ancora un'altra voce del menu senza descrizione"
    }
]
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
// Percorso del file JSON
$jsonFile = 'menu.json';

// Controlla se è una richiesta PUT
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT') {
    // Leggi i dati inviati dalla richiesta PUT
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

    // Decodifica i dati JSON
    $jsonData = json_decode($data, true);

    // Verifica se la decodifica è riuscita
    if ($jsonData !== null) {
        // Codifica nuovamente i dati come JSON
        $jsonString = json_encode($jsonData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        // Sovrascrivi il file JSON con i nuovi dati
        file_put_contents($jsonFile, $jsonString);

        // Restituisci una risposta di successo
        http_response_code(200);
        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Modifiche salvate con successo.'));
    } else {
        // Errore nella decodifica JSON
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Errore nella decodifica JSON.'));
    }
} else {
    // Tipo di richiesta non supportato
    http_response_code(405);
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Metodo non consentito.'));
}
?>
```

JavaScript file:

```
let menuData; // Variabile per archiviare i dati del menu

// Funzione per inizializzare la tabella del menu
async function initMenuTable() {
    const menuTable = document.getElementById('menu-table');

    // Carica i dati del menu dal file JSON
    try {
        const response = await fetch('menu.json');
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Errore nel caricamento dei dati del menu.');
        }
        menuData = await response.json();

        // Popola la tabella con i dati del menu
        menuData.forEach((item, index) => {
            const row = menuTable.insertRow();
            row.innerHTML = `<td>${item.tipologia}</td><td>${item.nome}</td><td><button onclick="modificaVoceMenu(${index})">Modifica</button></td><td><input type="text" id="nuovo-titolo-${index}" disabled><button onclick="confermaModifica(${index})">Conferma</button></td>`;
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

// Funzione per abilitare la modifica di una voce del menu
function modificaVoceMenu(index) {
    document.getElementById(`nuovo-titolo-${index}`).removeAttribute('disabled');
}

// Funzione per confermare la modifica e aggiornare i dati
function confermaModifica(index) {
    const nuovoTitolo = document.getElementById(`nuovo-titolo-${index}`).value;
    
    // Aggiorna il titolo nel menuData
    menuData[index].nome = nuovoTitolo;

    // Aggiorna la cella HTML con il nuovo valore
    const cellaDaModificare = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[index + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    cellaDaModificare.textContent = nuovoTitolo;

    // Disabilita l'input e nascondi il pulsante di conferma
    document.getElementById(`nuovo-titolo-${index}`).setAttribute('disabled', 'true');

    // Salva il menuData aggiornato nel file JSON
    salvaMenuData(menuData);
}

// Funzione per salvare il menuData aggiornato nel file JSON
function salvaMenuData(data) {
    fetch('menu.json', {
        method: 'PUT', // Metodo HTTP per sovrascrivere il file JSON
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Errore nel salvataggio delle modifiche.');
        }
        console.log('Modifiche salvate con successo.');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}

// Chiama la funzione per inizializzare la tabella del menu quando la pagina si carica
window.addEventListener('load', initMenuTable);
```

Thanks to everyone that will help me!

Comment: (1) Did you try implementing it thru ajax ? (2) Instead of using a json file , will you consider using a database approach ?

Comment: È solo per evitare di usare un database perché o o o ricevo mille errori in connessione, richieste, visualizzazione dei dati, ecc. Inoltre ho provato AJAX ma stava dando problemi. Ora ricevo un errore 405 restituito (Server: Windows 2012) e non so come aggirarlo. So che c'è qualcosa sul "WebDAVModule", ma non sono sicuro che questo sia il problema. C'è un modo per dire al server di accettare le richieste POST da HTTPS? @KenLee